# CellMouseDoubleClick fires multiple times on DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have WinForms application in c#.

I want to add event on my dynamically created DataGridView.
The action that i want to add on double click is deleting the clicked row.

The problem is that the events fires multiple times, for each row index higher that the one that is clicked.

For example I have 5 items in my DataGridView and i click on the second one.
The event fires 4 times and deletes 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th element.

If i click on the last one, it works ok (because he is the higher index).

Any ideas ...

Comment: Without seeing how you are deleting this row, Speculation is best you can hope for. You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of that, and I left some space for oportunity to remove one day multiple selected rows in case you need it

```
 if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hti.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
        }
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
```